# Tell the Rust compiler when two generic types are the same

Tags: generics, rust

I'm wondering if it is possible to tell to the Rust compiler that two generic types are the same.

In the specific case, I have a trait with a generic method and I want to implement a struct that has the same generic type as field, like in the following example:

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn foo<T>(&self, t: T) -> T;
}

struct Struct<T> {
    t: T
}

impl<T> Trait for Struct<T> {
    fn foo<U>(&self, t: U) {
        self.t
    }
}
```

Ofc here I have a compiler error because it expects U but have a T.
How can I handle this case?

Moving the generic outside foo creating `Trait<T>` is not an option.

Comment: But they are not necessarily the same with such declarations! `let s = Struct { t: 42 }; func(&s);` with `fn func(s: &dyn Trait) { s.foo("not an integer"); }` must be legal. Making `Trait` generic or giving it an associated type is the only way to go here.

Comment: This question is too broad to be generally answerable, basically amounting to "How do I implement this trait without implementing the trait?" The straightforward answer is "you can't" but you almost certainly have more specific needs than that, which we could probably help you with if you explain the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use associated types:

```rust
trait Trait {
    type U;
    fn foo(&self, t: Self::U) -> Self::U;
}

struct Struct<T> {
    t: T
}

impl<T: Copy> Trait for Struct<T> {
    type U = T;
    fn foo(&self, t: T) -> T {
        self.t
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=37846f95f22b3727b496fd683a4cf3e6)

PS: I added an extra `T: Copy` because `T` needs to be `Copy` to return `self.t` as it is a shared ref.

Comment: Depending on what the OP meant with “creating `Trait<T>` is not an option”, this might not be OK either. But this would be the way to go otherwise.

Comment: I think OP doesn't want `Trait<T>` because it allows multiple implementations of a single trait. But yea, now that you pointed it out, it's possible he doesn't want associated types either.

Comment: Well, the OP hasn't said why the OP doesn't want `Trait<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
fn foo<T>(&self, t: T) -> T;
```

in a trait means the method *must* work for all `T`, and your struct's field can't possibly have all of those types at the same time!

That is, this code will compile given the trait and struct definition:

```
fn main() {
    let x: Struct<i32> = Struct { t: 0 };
    let y: &str = x.foo("abc");
    let z: [i32; 2] = x.foo([0,0]);
}
```

and obviously `y` and `z` can't be `x.t`.

(after writing the answer, I see the point has already been made in mcarton's comment; I will delete it if he asks, but hopefully it's a bit clearer this way without requiring `dyn`).